# why do I need Iterator interface and why should I use it?

Tags: java

I am new to Java  so maybe to some of you my question will seem silly.

As I understand from some tutorial if I need to make on my custom object foreach the object must implement Iterable interface.

My question is why do I need Iterator interface and why should I use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned, `Iterable` is used in foreach loops.

Not everything can be used in a foreach loop, right? What do you think this will do?

```
for (int a : 10)
```

The designers of Java wanted to make the compiler able to spot this nonsense and report it to you as a compiler error. So they thought, "what kind of stuff can be used in a foreach loop?" "Well", they thought, "objects must be able to return an iterator". And this interface is born:

```
public interface Iterable<T> {
    /**
     * Returns an iterator over elements of type {@code T}.
     *
     * @return an Iterator.
     */
    Iterator<T> iterator();
}
```

The compiler can just check whether the object in the foreach loop implements `Iterable` or not. If it does not, spit out an error. You can think of this as a kind of "marker" to the compiler that says "Yes I can be iterated over!"

"What is an iterator then?", they thought again, "Well, an iterator should be able to return the next element and to return whether it has a next element. Some iterators should also be able to remove elements". So this interface is born:

```
public interface Iterator<E> {
    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if the iteration has more elements.
     * (In other words, returns {@code true} if {@link #next} would
     * return an element rather than throwing an exception.)
     *
     * @return {@code true} if the iteration has more elements
     */
    boolean hasNext();

    /**
     * Returns the next element in the iteration.
     *
     * @return the next element in the iteration
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if the iteration has no more elements
     */
    E next();

    /**
     * Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned
     * by this iterator (optional operation).  This method can be called
     * only once per call to {@link #next}.  The behavior of an iterator
     * is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the
     * iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this
     * method.
     *
     * @implSpec
     * The default implementation throws an instance of
     * {@link UnsupportedOperationException} and performs no other action.
     *
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the {@code remove}
     *         operation is not supported by this iterator
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the {@code next} method has not
     *         yet been called, or the {@code remove} method has already
     *         been called after the last call to the {@code next}
     *         method
     */
    default void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Iterator](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/iterator_pattern.htm) is design pattern, it allows to go through collection of same object in certain way, this also allow to hide implementation of store element and iteration mechanism from user. As you can see in javadoc many classes implements `Itarable` interface, not only collections. In example it allows you to iterate through two `List` implementations in same performance, when `ArrayList` give indexes in same time but `LinkedList` for give certain index need to go all elements previously to this number and this much slower. But when you get `Iterator` from this implementation you get same performance in both cases because iterate algorithm optimised in both list in different way. `ResultSet` is also iterator but it does not implement interface from `java.util` it allow to iterate in all result of query in db in same way and hide back structures responsibles for elements store and db participation. In example when you need some optimization you may make new ResultSet implementation query db per next result invoke or what ever you want, because it also decouple client code from elements storage realization and iteration algorithms.